# Populate nested collections with DataReader

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, dto, datareader

Imagine I have a stored procedure that should return three tables:

```
SELECT AID, AName
FROM AThings

SELECT BID, BName, AID
FROM BThings

SELECT CID, CName, BID
FROM CThings
```

In an class representation:

```
public class AThing
{
   int AID { get; set; }
   string AName { get; set;}
   Dictionary<int, BThing> BThingsColl { get; set;} 
}

public class BThing
{
   int BID { get; set; }
   string BName { get; set;}
   int AID { get; set; }
   List<CThing> CThingsColl { get; set;}
}

public class CThing
{
   int CID { get; set; }
   string CName { get; set;}
   int BID { get; set; }
}
```

`CThing` has a reference to `BThing`, `BThing` has a reference to `AThing`.

To executed the stored procedure, and to populate my object, I'm using a `DataReader`:

```
using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    var results = new Dictionary<int, AThing>();

    while(dr.Read())
    {
        var downloadedAThing = new AThing();
        downloadedAThing.BThingsColl = new Dictionary<int, BThing>();

        downloadedAThing.AID = dr.GetInt32(0);
        downloadedAThing.AName = dr.GetString(1);

        results.Add(downloadedAThing.AID, downloadedAThing);
    }

    if (dr.NextResult)
    {
        while(dr.Read())
        {
            var downloadedBThing = new BThing();
            downloadedBThing.CThingsColl = new List<CThing>();

            downloadedBThing.BID = dr.GetInt32(0);
            downloadedBThing.BName = dr.GetString(1);  
            downloadedBThing.AID = dr.GetInt32(2);

            results[downloadedBThing.AID].BThingsColl.Add(downloadedBThing.BID, downloadedBThing);
        }
    }

    if (dr.NextResult)
    {
        while(dr.Read())
        {
            var downloadedCThing = new CThing();

            downloadedCThing.CID = dr.GetInt32(0);
            downloadedCThing.CName = dr.GetString(1);  
            downloadedCThing.BID = dr.GetInt32(2);

            int AThingID = // How to retreive me?
            results[AThingID].BThingsColl[downloadedCThing.BID].Add(downloadedCThing);
        }
    }
}
```

- In the third nesting, how can I retreive the AThingID?
- Is there a more clever way to populate nested collections? I though about dictionaries as at first, but maybe there is a simpler/clearer pattern.
- What about more level nesting?

Answer (score 1):

Keeping with your existing code, I think the easiest way would be to create a temporary dictionary, and then add to it after creating the BThing:

```
Dictionary<int, int> BIDtoAID = new Dictionary<int, int>();
```

After creating downloadedBThing:

```
BIDtoAID.Add(downloadedBThing.BID, downloadedBThing.AID);
```

Then, while creating your CThing:

```
int AThingID = BIDtoAID[downloadedCThing.BID];
```

If you are dealing with many records, I think keeping a temporary dictionary with these IDs would be the most performant.